# If the localizations of two submodules with respect to any prime ideal are equal then the submodules are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I want to prove the following:

> Let R be a commutative ring with 1 and let N and L be two submodules of an R-module M. If the localizations of N and L with respect to any prime ideal of R are equal then $N=L$.

I have applied the fact that $D^{-1}\,(N+L)=D^{-1}\,N+D^{-1}L=D^{-1}N$ but this is not enough to say that $N+L=N$ so I couldnt say $L\subseteq N$.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to show that if $N_\mathfrak p\subseteq L_\mathfrak p$ for every $\mathfrak p$ then in fact $N\subseteq L$. You can do this as follows: take $x\in N$. By hypothesis $x$ is zero in $M_{\mathfrak p}/L_\mathfrak p=(M/L)_\mathfrak p$ for every prime $\mathfrak p$, that is $x$ is zero in $M/L$, that is $x\in L$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint : first prove that if $M$ is a $R$-module such that for all $\mathfrak{p}$ prime ideal $M_{\mathfrak{p}} = 0$ then $M$ is zero. For that, pick $m \in M$ and consider
$$ \text{Ann}(m) = \{r \in R\mid r\cdot m=0\}.$$
If you prove that this ideal is $R$ then $m = 0$.

Then apply this to $(N+L)/N$, using the fact that $(M/M')_{\mathfrak{p}}=M_{\mathfrak{p}}/M'_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for any $R$-modules $M$ and $M'$.